# How to loop through specific string values of a variable in Stata?

Tags: string, loops, stata

I want to loop through a specific subset vector of a string variable in Stata. I have a data set like:

```
id  country  effect  period
1   US       0.20    2
2   US       0.25    3
3   Japan    0.37    2
4   Germany  0.22    3
5   US       0.11    3
6   Japan    0.43    1
7   Ireland  0.30    1
...
```

I don't want to loop through all values of the country-variable, but only through specific values, e.g. US and Japan. I tried:

```
levelsof country if country=="US" | country=="Japan", local(countrylev)
levelsof period, local(periodlev) //periods are 1,2,3,4
mat m = J(2,4,.)
local i=1
local j=1

foreach x of local countrylev {
 foreach per of local periodlev {
    mat m[`i',`j']=`per' *2
    local ++j
    mat m[`i',`j']=`per' *3
    local ++j 
    mat m[`i',`j']=`per' *3
    local ++j 
    mat m[`i',`j']=`per' *4
    local ++i
    local j=1
 }
 matrix list m
}
```

However this only loops through "Japan"...

Comment: Describing the ultimate purpose of this might get you better advice.

Comment: This question has yet to yield an intelligible, clear and reproducible problem. I've commented on your revised code in an updated answer. As the code reduces to something trivial, I think you edited your real problem out.

Comment: You are totally right. Sorry for that. I'll delete my question as it is not value adding for other users.

Answer (score 3):

I have to guess that the answer lies in the data or the code you have represented by dots. For example, check for trailing spaces such as `"US "`.

For cycling over two distinct values, you can be direct and say

```
foreach c in US Japan { 
   <stuff> if country == "`c'" 
}
```

except that (as above) trailing spaces could undermine that. Use `trim()` if spaces are the problem.

It is often easier to map to a numeric variable and then use the distinct numeric values you want. That is especially true when you have blanks and/or other punctuation to handle too.  For more, see (e.g.) [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/index.html) (which is more relevant than the title implies; see Method 1).

UPDATE

Revised code makes matters more puzzling, not less. Your code seems to boil down 
to

```
mat m = J(2,4,.)

forval i = 1/2 {
    forval j = 1/4 {
        mat m[`i',`j']=`j'*2
        mat m[`i',`j']=`j'*3
        mat m[`i',`j']=`j'*3
        mat m[`i',`j']=`j'*4
    }
}

matrix li M
```

as listing the matrix each time around the loop doesn't seem important.

Indeed, the example seems to collapse to one line

```
mat M = (2,3,3,4)' * (1,2,3,4)
```

However, you may have simplified something important for you out of the problem to focus on what is problematic in terms of code.

Comment: Thanks! You are totally right. The problem is the content in the dots. I edited my question. The issue is that I receive a confirmability error r(503). I think there is a problem with the matrix 'm' after the first loop... Could you help me with this?

Comment: At a minimum, your `foreach per of local period` should be for periodlev, not period.